# React cannot handle counter properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple code which iterates through an array and logs them in the interval of 1000 ms as such :

```
  const arr = [1, 2, 3];
  let i = 0;
  const choice = () => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(arr[i++ % arr.length]);
      if (i === 8) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  choice();
```

Upon introducing React state into the code, the whole thing goes absolutely mad and starts counting out of the interval to a point that I reach almost infinite loop although the simple `console.log` instead of  react state works fine.

```
  const [ele, setEle] = React.useState(null);
  const arr = [1, 2, 3];
  let i = 0;
  const choice = () => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setEle(arr[i++ % arr.length]);
      if (i === 8) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  choice();

return( 
    <h1>{ele}</h1>
)
```

I wonder how I can achieve the effect using the state with the current code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-dubinsky-kbl5m

Comment: where is your i++ counter ? and `i` variable should be a state also, because u will increment it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current implementation, every render of the component is initializing a *new* interval, so you get lots of intervals running simultaneously, each of which initiate even more intervals. Use `setTimeout` instead, so that every render only initializes *exactly one* action to take place in the future.

Since it's the *index* of the array that changes each time, consider using *that* as state instead:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [i, setI] = React.useState(0);
  const arr = [1, 2, 3];
  if (i !== 8) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setI(i + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{arr[i % arr.length]}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the other answer somewhat unsatisfying because it requires a new timeout to be generated each time.  It is possible to set up a single setInterval which requires a useRef to get an up-to-date setI into the timer.  The empty useEffect dependencies ensures the setInterval is not re-run on each state update.

```
const App = () => {
  const [i, setI] = React.useState(0);
  const timer = React.useRef();

  timer.current = () => setI(i+1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      timer.current();
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    };
  }, [])

  return <div>{i}</div>;
}
```